# Registry on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, registry, 64-bit

I have a problem with the registry in Windows x64. I need to get a value added through file.reg:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\My Soft]
"Str1" = "Assa"
"Str2" = "142Z5214GGAAVGA"
```

In the code, I do:

```
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\My Soft", 0,NULL,0,    KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,NULL,&hKey,&dwDis))
/*
Get the value by RegQueryValueEx... 
*/
```

In a 32-bit Windows is good. In a 64-bit value is empty.

PS:
Sorry for my English by Google Translate ^_^

Comment: You say you need to get a value, but you're calling `RegCreateKeyEx`. Do you actually need to _create_ it? If so, it's probably created in HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node.

Comment: Did you try to remove the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag? This redirects to a different registry location on 64-bit platforms. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx) you can find more information.

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox on VS2012, change the Platform target to AnyCPU.

Comment: C++ and `AnyCPU`? How's that going to work?

Comment: Viva64 Knowledge Base: WOW6432Node and API-functions RegOpenKeyEx / RegEnumKeyEx - http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0029/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you need to get a value, but you're calling `RegCreateKeyEx`. Do you actually need to *create* it? If so, it's probably created in HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node` ?

The default 64-bit version of Registry Editor (Regedit.exe) that is included with 64-bit versions of Windows displays both 64-bit keys and 32-bit keys. The WOW64 registry redirector presents 32-bit programs with different keys for 32-bit program registry entries. In the 64-bit version of Registry Editor, 32-bit keys are displayed under the following registry key.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097)